# TFODAPI - Model fine tuning does not work

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

Working with Tensorflow Object Detection API I see that confidence reported for every detected object is over 50%. I would like to see detection results at lower score values because, with some images I'm working on, many relevant targets (persons and/or cars) are missed.
I do also would like to change score_threshold value to speed NMS up (according to https://becominghuman.ai/tensorflow-object-detection-api-basics-of-detection-2-2-28b348495eec ).

I'm working with "ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17" model, so I changed "ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config" in object_detection\samples\configs:

"matched_threshold" and "unmatched_threshold" from 0.5 to 0.3,

"score_threshold" from 1e-8 to 0.2

and also

"iou_threshold" from 0.6 to 0.8

Then, from "object_detection" folder I run:

"
python export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path .\samples\configs\ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix .\ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17\model.ckpt --output_directory .\fine_tuned_model
"

and I get the "frozen_inference_graph.pb".
I can also prepare the relevant "frozen_inference_graph.pbtxt" where I see that iou_threshold actually changed from 0.6 to 0.8 so I suppose also the other parameters changed correctly.

Then I change object_detection_tutorial.ipynb in order to work with the new model:
I change 
"MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'"
to 
"MODEL_NAME = 'fine_tuned_model'" 
then I execute it step by step, skipping the "Download Model" section.
I do see a difference with the 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17' because in the dogs "image1.jpg" I see that there are 2 bounding boxes around the dog on the right, I suppose due to the higher iou_threshold value.
What I'm not able is to detect objects with a confidence score lower than 50%. It is not that relevant with test images, but changing the images I see many missing objects.
I think I'm missing something but I'm not able to figure out what.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer to my doubts.

Simply, it was simply necessary to specify min_score_thresh value as a parameter for "visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array" function!!!
 :O:O:O